# Can't upload multiple files with direct creator upload on Cloudflare?

Tags: next.js, cloudflare

When trying to upload two files, the response does not come back continuously. I wonder what needs to be changed. **Uploading one file works fine**.

The following code is an example.
One variable `'img' (files.img[0])` uploads successfully,
but when creating two variables 'img' and 'img2' for uploading,
the upload does not work.
**Changing the name in `imgForm.append` doesn't seem to work either.**

```js
// Home.tsx
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            multiple={true}
            {...register("images")}
          />

// pages/api/cloudflare/upload.ts
const imgForm = new FormData();
            const twoArray = new Array(2).fill(0).map((el, idx) => el + idx);

            if (fields.title && files.img) {
              const title = fields.title[0];
              const img = files.img[0];
              const img2 = files.img[1];

              const fileData = await fs.promises.readFile(img.filepath);
              const fileData2 = await fs.promises.readFile(img2.filepath);

              const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: img.mimetype! });
              const blob2 = new Blob([fileData2], { type: img2.mimetype! });

              const file = new File([blob], title, {
                type: img.mimetype!,
              });
              const file2 = new File([blob2], title + "앞", {
                type: img2.mimetype!,
              });
              imgForm.append("file", file);
              imgForm.append("file", file2);
            }

            // The uploadURL is the URL received from Cloudflare
            const { data } = await axios.post(uploadURL, imgForm, {
              headers: {
                ContentType: "multipart/form-data",
              },
            });
```